# How to create a trigger, to trigger daily but not on Sundays

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

How to create a trigger, to trigger daily but not on Sundays.

Hello, everyone I want to create a trigger to trigger daily everyday in the week but except on Sunday. This the code I tried it works but I'm quite confused on how to confirm it correctly do the job because I noticed excecutions on Sunday as well. Please guide me if there's any other recommended codes I would try as well.

```
function setTriggerNoSunday() {
  var today = new Date(); // Get the current date and time

  // Set the trigger to execute today at the desired time
  var triggerDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 14, 25);

  // Check if the trigger date is a Sunday (0), and if so, increment it by one day
  if (triggerDate.getDay() === 0) {
    triggerDate.setDate(triggerDate.getDate() + 1);
  }

  // Create the trigger using the calculated trigger date and time
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('heyTrigger')
    .timeBased()
    .at(triggerDate)
    .create();
}
```

This codes below they works

```
function heyTrigger() {
  var startTime = new Date();
  startTime.setHours(17); //Allows to set a preferable time to start
  startTime.setMinutes(30); //The default time to set at 10.30
  startTime.setSeconds(0);

  var endTime = new Date();
  endTime.setHours(22); //Allows to set a preferable time to end
  endTime.setMinutes(0); //The default time to set at 22.00 (24H format is important to function the trigger)
  endTime.setSeconds(0); //30 mins extra to get the next date

  var intervalMinutes = 30; //Works with a 30 Minutes interval 

  var currentTime = new Date();
  var nextRunTime = new Date();
  nextRunTime.setTime(Math.ceil(currentTime.getTime() / (intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000)) * (intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000));

  if (nextRunTime < startTime) {
    nextRunTime = startTime;
  }

  while (nextRunTime <= endTime) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('dioSamaDIO')
      .timeBased()
      .at(nextRunTime)
      .create();

    nextRunTime.setTime(nextRunTime.getTime() + (intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000));
  }
}



function dioSamaDIO() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var clearSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEST#");
  var numRows = 3; // Starting number of rows
  var numCols = 3; // Number of columns

  var rangeA2 = clearSheet.getRange("A2");
  var rangeA3 = clearSheet.getRange("A3");
  var dateA2 = rangeA2.getValue();
  var dateA3 = rangeA3.getValue();

  // Compare the dates in cells A2 and A3
  if (dateA3 > dateA2) {
    rangeA2.clearContent();
    rangeA2.setValue(dateA3); // Move the data in A3 to A2
  } else if (dateA2 > dateA3) {
    rangeA3.clearContent();
  }

  // Delete rows B3, B4, B5, etc.
  for (numRows = 3; numRows <= clearSheet.getLastRow(); numRows++) {
    clearSheet.deleteRow(numRows);
    if (numRows >= 3) { // Break the loop after 1 row has been deleted
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply create a unique daily trigger (or any other time based trigger) and add a conditional return in the triggered function like this :

```
var today = new Date();
if(today.getHours()<7 || today.getHours()>19 || today.getDay()==0){return};
```

In this example, the function is executed only between 7 AM and 7 PM on weekdays and saturday.